# How can I return multiple levels/groups of values from a multi-index dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Here is my multi-index dataframe:

```
# Index Levels
outside = ['G1','G1','G1','G2','G2','G2']
inside = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
hier_index = list(zip(outside,inside))
hier_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(hier_index)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,2),index=hier_index,columns=['A','B'])
df.index.names = ['Group','Num']
df
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
                  A           B
Group   Num     
G1      1     0.147027  -0.479448
        2     0.558769   1.024810
        3    -0.925874   1.862864
G2      1    -1.133817   0.610478
        2     0.386030   2.084019
        3    -0.376519   0.230336
```

What I want to achieve is to return the values in `Group` `G1` and `G2`, `Num` `1` and `3`, which looks like this:

```
G1     1     0.147027   -0.479448
       3    -0.925874    1.862864
G2     1    -1.133817    0.610478
       3    -0.376519    0.230336
```

I've tried

```
df.loc[['G1','G2']].loc[[1,3]]
```

but it shows nothing.

Then I tried

```
df.xs([['G1','G2'],[1,3]])
```

but it returns

> TypeError: '(['G1', 'G2'], [1, 3])' is an invalid key.

Is there any way I can just make it return the values in `Group` `G1` and `G2`, `Num` `1` and `3`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with lists:

```
df1 = df.loc[(['G1','G2'], [1,3]), :]
print (df1)
                  A         B
Group Num                    
G1    1    2.165594  0.466762
      3    0.451996  0.125071
G2    1    2.783947  0.176145
      3    0.169508  0.071441
```

Or use [slicers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df1 = df.loc[idx[['G1','G2'], [1,3]], :]
print (df1)
                  A         B
Group Num                    
G1    1    0.617367 -1.010116
      3   -0.990257 -1.262942
G2    1    1.336134 -0.198787
      3   -0.310426  1.063520
```

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to  `.loc`, you can also use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) like this:

```
df.query('Group in ["G1", "G2"] and Num in [1, 3]')
```

which also returns:

```
                  A         B
Group Num                    
G1    1   -1.749477 -0.276759
      3    0.888542 -0.656236
G2    1    0.757631 -1.091000
      3   -1.203232  1.702107
```

If you like you can also use parameters in the queries using `@` which might come in handy if you have long lists:

```
num_sel = [1, 3]
df.query('Group in ["G1", "G2"] and Num in @num_sel')
```

yielding the same output.

You can then also easily add additional constraints on the column entries, e.g. that the values in `A` have to be greater than `0`:

```
df.query('Group in ["G1", "G2"] and Num in [1, 3] and A > 0')
```

which returns

```
                  A         B
Group Num                    
G1    3    0.888542 -0.656236
G2    1    0.757631 -1.091000
```

Comment: Didn't know we could use query like this. Thank you for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 1):

The `.loc` indexing method of `pandas` takes the level of each index as an argument:

```
df.loc[['G1','G2'], [1,3],:]
```

Being that your dataframe has 2 indices and 1 level of columns, the `.loc` method will take 3 arguments, one for each level of the index and one for the columns.

> *You can read more with the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index).*

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It helps a lot!